# Matrix addition and subtraction using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am asked to add and subtract two 2-D matrix using pointers and `malloc()` functon in C.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,row,col,n;
    double *a,*b,*c,*d;
 
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf(" %d",&col);
    n=row*col;
    a = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    b = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    c = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    d = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    printf("Enter the numbers of First Matrix, A:\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", (*(a + i) + j));
        }
    }
    printf("Enter the numbers of Second Matrix, B:\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", (*(b + i) + j));
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            (*(c + i) + j) = (*(a + i) + j) + (*(b + i) + j);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            (*(d + i) + j) = (*(a + i) + j) - (*(b + i) + j);
        }
    }
    printf("A+B=\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",(*(c + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("A-B=\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",(*(d + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 
 
    return 0;
}
```

Now whenever i am running this, the compiler is keep showing me

> **[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment**

[image]

I am taking the arrays as double as user can insert any real number.

Why is it showing so ?

Comment: BTW, you don't always need two nested loops: `for(size_t i=0; i < n; ++i) { c[i] = a[i] + b[i]; }` or `for(size_t i=0; i < n; ++i) { *(c + i) = *(a + i) + *(b + i); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `(*(c+i)+j)` is like `c[i]+j`, so your left side is not an [lvalue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160). For example, if your matrix `c` was [[1,2],[3,4]], then `(*(c+0)+1)` would be the same as `c[0]+1` which is 2, and then you try to do `2 = something` thus you get that error. To solve this, first you need to move the `*` outside the parenthesis, but even then your logic is a bit flawed. You want to use something like `*(c+col*i+j)`.

This code takes the matrix as input and prints it, try looking at how I used the pointers and apply it to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int i,j,row,col,n;
    double *a;

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf(" %d",&col);
    n = row*col;

    a = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    printf("Enter the numbers of First Matrix, A:\n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<col; j++){
            scanf("%lf", (a+ col*i + j));
        }
    }

    printf("A:\n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(j=0; j<col;j++){
            printf("%lf ", *(a+ col*i + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```